# Bash For Loop Syntax Error

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax-error

I am trying to perform a simple for loop, but it keeps telling me there is a syntax error near do. I have tried to find some answers online, but nothing seems to be quite answering my question.

The for loop is as so. All it wants to do is find the differences between two folders:

```
#!/bin/bash
for word in $LIST; do
 diff DIR1/config $word/config
done
exit
```

The syntax error is near do. It says "Syntax error near unexpected token 'do '". $LIST is set outside of this script by the program that calls it.

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Comment: What does `$LIST` expand to? Also, can you give the exact error?

Comment: $LIST expands to a list like so:
DIR2 DIR3 DIR4

Comment: This doesn't contribute to the syntax error, but you need to prefix `DIR1` (assuming it is a variable) and `word` with  a dollar sign to get their value: `diff "$DIR1/config" "$word/config"`.

Comment: Also, the syntax error is: Syntax error near unexpected token 'do'

Comment: This is not the code, the full code and nothing but the code. We need more information to debug this.

Comment: I added the rest of the script, there was not much else to it. Hope it helps out.

Answer (score 3):

That's certainly valid syntax for `bash` so I'd be checking whether you may have special characters somewhere in the file, such as CR/LF at the ends of your lines.

Assuming you're on a UNIXy system, `od -xcb scriptname.sh` should show you this.

In addition, you probably also want to use `$word` rather than just `word` since you'll want to evaluate the variable.

Another thing to check is that you *are* actually running this under `bash` rather than some "lesser" shell. And it's often handy to place a `set -x` within your script for debugging purposes as this outputs lines before executing them (use `set +x` to turn this feature off).

One last thing to check is that `LIST` is actually set to something, by doing `echo "[$LIST]"` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Focus on how `LIST`'s value is set, since that is what seems to be the cause of the error.

Comment: Actually, chepner, I've seen this sort of thing before with incorrect line endings, such as "mysterious" errors on what seems like valid syntax, and inability to run shells from shebang lines.

Comment: LIST's value is set in an automation program which calls this particular script. Also, I tried that command, no CR/LF seems to have snuck into the program

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree; I just didn't word that comment well. I assumed that the value of `LIST` was set in the file and its value seemed a likely source of the carriage return that was causing the issue.